# How to use strings and doubles in the same function in C++

Tags: c++, string, function, double

For a class project I need to get a customer's info all in one function (that includes their name, room number, etc.) so I need to use doubles and strings in the same function. Is there anyway to do this or an alternative if their isn't?

The project wants us to pass values by reference.

```
//Prints a statement for each overnight customer.

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const double sales_tax_rate = 0.055;

//Function prototypes
string customerInformation(string &customer_name, string &date_of_bill, 
string &hotelormotel_name, double &room_rate, double &number_of_nights, 
double &phone_charges, double &room_number);

int main()
{
    string customer_name, dummy, date_of_bill, hotelormotel_name;
    double room_rate = 0;
    double number_of_nights = 0;
    double phone_charges = 0;
    double room_number = 0;
    double room_cost;
    double subtotal;
    double total;
    double taxes;
    int counter = 1;
    char repeat;

    do
    {
        counter += 1;
        taxes = 0;
        total = 0;
        subtotal = 0;
        room_cost = 0;

        customerInformation(customer_name, room_rate, number_of_nights, 
        phone_charges, room_number, date_of_bill, hotelormotel_name);

        room_cost = room_rate * number_of_nights;
        taxes = sales_tax_rate * room_cost;
        subtotal = taxes + room_cost;
        total = subtotal + phone_charges;

        cout << hotelormotel_name << endl << endl;
        cout << "Date:             " << date_of_bill << endl;
        cout << "Customer's Name:  " << customer_name << endl;
        cout << "Room Number:      " << room_number << endl;
        cout << "Number of Nights: " << number_of_nights << endl;
        cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << endl;
        cout << "Room Rate:     $" << room_rate << endl;
        cout << "Room Cost:     $" << room_cost << endl;
        cout << "Taxes:         $" << taxes << endl;
        cout << "Subtotal:      $" << subtotal << endl << endl;
        cout << "Phone Charges: $" << phone_charges << endl << endl;
        cout << "TOTAL DUE:     $" << total << endl << endl;
        cout << "Thank you for staying at " << hotelormotel_name << "!" << 
        endl;
        cout << "Drive safely and please come again!" << endl << endl;

        cout << "Would you like to run this program again? (Y or N): ";
        cin >> repeat;
        getline(cin, dummy);
        cout << endl;
    } while (repeat == 'Y' || repeat == 'y');
}

string customerInformation(string &customer_name, string &date_of_bill, 
string &hotelormotel_name, double &room_rate, double &number_of_nights, 
double &phone_charges, double &room_number)
{
    cout << "Please enter the following information: " << endl;
    cout << "Hotel/Motel Name: ";
    getline(cin, hotelormotel_name);
    cout << "Customer Name:    ";
    getline(cin, customer_name);
    cout << "Date:             ";
    getline(cin, date_of_bill);
    cout << "Room Number:      ";
    cin >> room_number;

    do
    {
        cout << "Number of Nights: ";
        cin >> number_of_nights;
        if (number_of_nights <= 0)
             cout << "Error: Invalid data entered, please try again.\n";
    } while (number_of_nights <= 0);

    cout << endl;

    do
    {
        cout << "Room Rate:     $";
        cin >> room_rate;
        if (room_rate <= 0)
            cout << "Error: Invalid data entered, please try again.\n";
    } while (room_rate <= 0);

    do
    {
        cout << "Phone Charges: $";
        cin >> phone_charges;
        if (phone_charges < 0)
            cout << "Error: Invalid data entered, please try again.\n";
    } while (phone_charges < 0);

    cout << endl;

     return date_of_bill, customer_name, room_number, room_rate, 
number_of_nights, phone_charges, hotelormotel_name;
}
```

Comment: How is your program not doing what you want? Doesn't your function *already* accept both strings and doubles?

Comment: Every time I run it I get this error:
Error C2664 'std::string customerInformation(std::string &,std::string &,std::string &,double &,double &,double &,double &)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'double' to 'std::string &' Project1 c:\users\worth\downloads\lab8-1-wortham.cpp 39

Comment: Wait you want to **return** all those things? You don't need to. You passed them ***by reference*** which means if you change their value in the function, those changes are passed back out to the caller. Don't add them all to the *return* statement.

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And learn how to create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I also get a lot of errors like:
Error (active) E0434 a reference of type "double &" (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type "std::string" Project1 C:\Users\worth\Downloads\Lab8-1-Wortham.cpp 39

Comment: You need to pass the arguments in the order they are declared in the function prototype. For instance, `room_rate` is the 4th parameter not the 2nd.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a struct with all that info?

```
   struct customerinfo {
   string customer_name;
   string date_of_bill;
   string hotelormotel_name;
   double room_rate;
   double number_of_nights; 
   double phone_charges; 
   double room_number;
   };
```

and then you return a variable from the type struct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes There is an alternative of doing this using structs, you can create your own struct as follow

```
struct customerInfo { 
      string customer_name, dummy, date_of_bill, hotelormotel_name;
      double room_rate;
      double number_of_nights;
      double phone_charges;
      double room_number;
      double room_cost;
      double subtotal;
      double total;
      double taxes;
};
```

**Then you can pass an object of struct type to a function as follow**

```
//Function prototypes
string customerInformation(customerInfo tempCustomer);
```

**And you can use this tempCustomer as follow**

```
string customerInformation(customerInfo tempCustomer){
         cin>>tempCustomer.customer_name;
         //you can call all attributes and assign them values accordingly
         //to return a particular value you can do
         return tempCustomer.customer_name;
}
```

Comment: from this method you can return a complete object (by changing return type of function from string to customerInfo).